# Why does scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b fail to print iteration details despite appropriate inputs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, anaconda, spyder

**Goal:**
To view the value of the objective function at each iteration for `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b`.

**Problem:**
Giving the optional argument `iprint=1` should cause output to be printed. However, doing so does not result in any output.

**Other info:**
I am using the Anaconda 4.3 distribution of Python 2.7 on a Windows 7 machine, Spyder IDE with IPython console.

**Example Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

A = np.random.rand(20,40)
b = np.random.rand(20,)
x0 = np.ones((40,))

def objective_func(x,A,b):
    objective = np.sum((A.dot(x)-b)**2) + np.sum(np.abs(x))
    return objective

def gradient_func(x,A,b):
    gradient = 2*A.T.dot(A.dot(x)-b) + 2*x/np.sqrt(x**2 + 10**(-8))
    return gradient

x_bar = opt.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func=objective_func,
                          x0=x0,
                          fprime = gradient_func,
                          args=(A,b),
                          iprint=1)
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to call the function? My apologies for this provocative comment. This was meant as advice to add example code for reproducing the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One solution is to use a lambda function as the callback function. This allows one to pass A, b to the callback function in addition to x.